# What does $$@ mean in a makefile?

Tags: makefile

I'm porting a makefile from AIX to Linux - it's falling over on this line:

```
program.o : header1.h header2.h
program : $$@.o lib1.a lib2.a lib3.a
```

The error is:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `$@.o', needed by `program'.  Stop.
```

Does anyone recognise this $$@ variable? I can't find any reference to it anywhere.

Thanks!

Comment: I found documentation for it [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html). I've never used this feature before so I can't tell you any more than that.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks - will have a read.

Comment: Yeah. That is either an error like H2CO3 indicated or an attempt at using Secondary Expansion like WumpusQ.Wumbley indicated.

Comment: I just noticed you're going the opposite way from what I thought - from AIX to Linux. This `$$@` appears to be a GNU extension so I'd expect it to be used mainly on Linux and all the porting problems to be in the opposite direction

Comment: @H2CO3: It wouldn't make sense as `$@`, since that variable isn't available in the prereq list. (I mean, the author may have intended `$@`, made a typo *and* been wrong, but that's assuming a lot.) Secondary Expansion seems the most likely explanation.

Comment: It would help if we could see the whole makefile, or at least confirm that it works in AIX.

Comment: Of course, GNU make works fine on AIX (as with just about every other POSIX-like system, plus Windows, VMS, OS/2, even Amiga).  No reason it couldn't be a GNU make makefile even if it was previously on AIX.

Comment: @Beta Oh, fair enough, I missed that it was int the dependency part...

Answer (score 2):

This rule must be in a section marked

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
```

The first `$` is expanded in the first pass yielding `$@.o` and then the second pass produces `program.o` as usual.

This is a GNU make feature.  You should ensure that GNU make (rather than some other) is being used on the target and that it's up to date.  You can do this with

```
make --version
```

Version 4 is available, but 3.8x ought to be fine.

The relevant documentation is [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion).

Answer (score 2):

If your make supports $$@, then $$@ would just evaluate to program on this line of this makefile.

$$@ can be the same as the name of the target on a DEPENDENCY (not command) line.  In this sense the makefile you have is correct (the $$@ is on a line where it's supposed to be).  $$@ isn't supported by all make programs.

According to the "Managing Projects with Make" book I use, $$@ means the same as $@  - the name of the target  - but $$@ and $@ are used in different places in a makefile:

$@ can only be used on a command line

target : dependency1 dependency2

command1 >> $@

$$@ can only be used on a dependency line as in:

docmk : $$@.c

EVALUATES TO:

docmk : docmk.c